# How do you keep the default WYSIWYG active when using a custom template?

Tags: wysiwyg

I've created a custom template for my "About Us" page because it need more options than what the static "page.php" file had to offer.

However the content that i enter into my "About Us" page from the default WYSIWYG editor on the back end doesn't appear on the new template obviously because i'm not calling in that template part (if that's even the right term for it).

Just to be clear when i create a custom template and need to call in a custom Field Group i'm using

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'content_area' ); ?>
```

However i will state that on this template page i'm not using a loop in this particular php file, is that not ok. Do loops need to be part of all php pages? Maybe i should start there.

Here's my code

```
/*
Template Name: About Us
*/

include(TEMPLATEPATH."/header-internal.php");


<div class="container-space"></div>

<div class="container-main">

  some content goes here

<div class="divider-btm"></div>

<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'content_area' ); ?>

</div>



<!--Update Solution Attempt-->

 <?php
 $args = array(
  ' post_type' => 'content_area'
 );
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 ?>

 <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while( $the_query->have_posts() :
 $the_query->have_posts(); ) ?>

 <h3><?php the_field( 'header' ); ?></h3>
 <p class="desc"><?php the_field( 'content_area' ); ?></p>

 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: I don't get the blockquote feature here, when i use it doesn't present my code as is but rather cuts out some of it so i try to just paste it without using it and it still won't show up right. I haven't been able to figure it out yet unfortunately and it's hurting my potential to get good answers back as a result. Not sure what's up?

Comment: what is in the file `content-content_area.php` you're calling via `get_template_part`?

Comment: What you write in the WYSIWYG editor is normally printed via `the_content` function, but this works *inside* the loop, however for single page template, you can simply use `the_post();` immediately after included the header and then `the_content();` in your `content-content_area.php`. A tip: you can use `get_header('internal');` to include your header.

Comment: @Milo I think i mixed concepts up. The "get_template_part" was calling "content_area.php" but there is no "content_area.php" I was actually trying to call a content post type in which case i believe i should've created a custom $query = new WP_Query( $args ) with an array parameter of " 'post_type' => 'content_area' " that would require a loop. So i was mixing concepts completely. Your advice on other posts though have been golden, that one nugget of understanding that $the_query is a custom variable opened up a world of understanding.

Comment: @G.M. awesome tip on the get_header() that works beautifully and is way easier to remember. I'm going to try your suggestion as well and am about to post the latest attempt prior to trying out your solution which crashed my 'About' page.

Comment: @MARS If the code you used is the one you posted is wrong. There is a syntax error on `<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while( $the_query->have_posts() :
 $the_query->have_posts(); ) ?>` should be `<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->have_posts(); ?>`

Comment: @G.M. thank you i see what was wrong there. It works now but it makes my WP edit header (that little small edit header that appears above your live site when logged in as admin) disappear and make the page a mile and half long and never gets to the footer which i'm leaning towards assuming is because of my code not working even after the syntax correction.

Comment: @G.M. going back to your previous answer and working on the basis that there is no "content_area.php" file and that i just want to include the content entered into the default WYSIWYG editor onto my template static About page, would i just enter a simple loop of if, while and endif and include the_post() function after the if/while loop for this to work? I'll test it out as the CPT solution isn't working for me on this particular page. Thanks

Comment: @G.M. the the_post() and the_content() functions worked great on my About page however i'm curious how can a client add a header inside of a WYSIWYG if it doesn't appear to be an option?

Comment: A _header_ you mean a `<h1>`, `<h2>` and so on? In the WYSIWYG editor, show extended (recond row of) buttons, clicking the last button in first row or type `Alt + Shift + Z`. Write some text, then select it and in the dropdown menu on the left of second row of buttons choose *'Heading 1'* or *'Heading 2'* and so on.